# Return back data horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am kinda lost in here.

I have a table with multiple duplicate values in the same column which i want to return back with S/N and Group as one unique value and then the price of each package in separate column as ('1D' AS DAILY, '1W' AS WEEKLY, AND '1M' AS 'MONTHLY').

[image]

am using MS SQL 2012

Thanks in Advance

regards,
Adnan

Answer (score 3):

```
select [S/N], [group],
       sum(case when package = '1D' then price else 0 end) as [daily price],
       sum(case when package = '1W' then price else 0 end) as [weekly price],
       sum(case when package = '1M' then price else 0 end) as [monthly price]
from rates
group by [S/N], [group]
```

Comment: wow that was fast. Thank you am gonna try it and give you my feedback

Comment: thanks alot buddy!! Working as desired and that was very simple and unexpected

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the PIVOT operator:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Rates') is not NULL  drop table #Rates

create table #Rates(
    S_N  int not null,
    _group varchar(10) not null,
    Package char(2) not null,
    price int not null
)

insert into #Rates
values (8, 'D'   , '1M', 3700)
,(8, 'I-DC','1M', 1750)
,(8,  'TB', '1M', 7000)
,(12, 'A', '1D', 80)
,(12, 'A', '1W', 480)
,(12, 'A', '1M', 1800)
,(12, 'B', '1D', 90)
,(12, 'B', '1W', 540)
,(12, 'B', '1M', 2100)

select S_N, _group, pvt.[1D] as "DailyPrice1D", pvt.[1W] as "WeeklyPrice1W", pvt.[1M] as "MonthlyPrice1M"
from #Rates
pivot(avg(price) FOR Package in ("1D", "1W", "1M")) pvt
ORDER by S_N
```

Do you need more explanation or is this code sample enough?
For more information here is the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: will give that try as well for an idea